# Javascript bbcode preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope the title isn't misleading - I found it a bit difficult to come up with one for this question. Here's the issue:

My site uses a system similar to bbcodes for color-formatting of texts. For instance, `1 translates to span `style='color #FFFFFF'` and ´5 to span `style='color #00FF00'`. This works pretty well, the solution I'm using now for sent data works via PHP (first finding the used codes, saving them to an array, then using the `str_replace` function. This works fine on displaying the end result after the DB insert, etc.

However, now I'd like to preview the texts using the same 'colorcodes' using javascript. I'd need some input on that!

The dataset I'm working with will be an array; e.g.

´1 => #FF0000,
´6 => #00FF00

and so forth. At present our database for these colorcodes has some ~100 entries.

In php the whole process isn't very resource intensive because the whole text is scanned just once for occurrence of the colorcodes. In the case of the javascript preview, I'd imagine this to be a horror - for every `onkeyup` event scan the whole text for colorcodes and replace them?

In theory, what I imagine doable would be monitoring which keys are pressed, and if the pressed key for instance is ´ save this key and the next one pressed to a variable and then call the bbcode-replacer for that one. (replace ´1 with span style='color: ...)

Would this even be practical? Are there any libraries (I'm using jquery so far) that would help with it?

Comment: So the numbers have to be replaced with codes as soon as its typed in ?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that'd be the resource-friendlist way! I'm not sure how to deal with it when the text is changed though, or if this would even create new problems.

Comment: What if the user really wanted to type in number 1 ?

Comment: That's why I'd need to monitor if ` or ´ and a number (or letter) are pressed directly after each other. Here are some more of the codes we use, for clarification: ` `1 ``2 ``b ``d `f ´x ´ü ´ä `

Comment: How about showing the color codes on click of something like a Preview button, that should reduce some resource intensive work

Comment: We've got that already, but our playerbase is still bugging me about extending the preview feature with the colorcodes - sadly.

Comment: Then I can't come up with anything better than checking for last two/three  chars on keyup() event and check against a predefined object map. Eg. `obj["``d"] ` and then replacing the text

Comment: I see - so instead of monitoring which key is pressed after a specific character, check the last 2-3 letters behind the position of the last keyup event? Sounds practical enough - I'll give it a try!